# CodeIgniter Sessions and userdata

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

all.
I'm using CodeIgniter (2.0.3), and Tank_Auth.
I set some userdata into the session at login time, and my config is set so it is saved on the database.
I subclassed the CI_controller class (MY_controller), so in the constructor i check if user is logged in. That way, every descendant controller can't be accessed unauthorized.
I've also subclassed the Session class to fix the regenerating session and AJAX problem (http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/138823/)
As per my config, session expiration time is 7200 secs (2 hours), and regeneration is 5 mins (300 secs)
The problem is as follow:

- User A logs in. A session is generated and saved in database, along with the corresponding userdata.
- User A stays logged in but does not make any request (say, for instance, he/she leaves the browser open and goes away)
- User B logs in two hours later.
- Session of user A expires (7200 secs), and the constructor of the session library, called by the requests made by user B, delete the user A session from database,

  ```
  $this->_sess_gc(); // Line number 122 of /system/libraries/session.php
  ```

(The same situation is arised by the mere expiration of the session, since the session class function sess_destroy erases it from the database, but i believe this course of action makes the point clearer, and is also a real one i've traced)

- User A comes back and makes an AJAX request to the server. In that request, the MY_controller constructor checks if user is logged

  ```
  if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
  ```

For that, it PREVIOUSLY loads the session library, which in turn calls the Session class constructor, which, in line 106 says:

```
    if ( ! $this->sess_read())
    {
        $this->sess_create();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->sess_update();
    }
```

- A new session is created, but with no userdata, so everything that depends on that data afterwards this point, starts to fail. BUT the is_logged_in() function still returns true. So i cant detect it.

I believe its a farily naive fail, so it must not be on the CI or the tank_auth or session classes, but in my own logic. But after hours of searching/digging/debugging, couldn't find a clue.
Can anyone pinpoint the error in my logic?
I paste my config (the session relevant part), and the MY_controller subclass.
Thank you for any help.

MY_Controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('tank_auth/users');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
        {
        header('Location:'. site_url('login_controller'));
        }
    }
}
```

Config

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is to log out inactive users, why not do that using cookies, codeigniter already helps you do that since sess_expiration is already set to true

Comment: Hi @JamesOkpeGeorge. Yes, i'm trying to log out "expired" users. But, instead of that, the code i've implemented just recreate the session and keeps the user logged in. Thats my problem, precisely. Can you be more specific or let me know what i'm missing? Many thanks for replying.

Comment: Try to repopulate your session userdata, on a new request, because the userdatas are destroyed when user becomes inactive. So basically, it would be like the user was logged out and is now making a fresh login to the site.

Comment: So, @JamesOkpeGeorge, should I subclass the _sess_create() function to add the user data again? Is this the normal procedure in these cases? Sounds to me like a nasty hack, actually. I'm very confused with this issue. Can you clarify a little bit further, please? Or provide me with some reference to read more on the subject?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my question? I'm not very experienced on stackoverflow, and may be there is a better way to ask? I'm surprised that there are so few anwsers, and from only 1 user (btw, thans again @JamesOkpeGeorge) This is an important problem for me and can't resolve it yets, so any help is still welcome! Thanks!